# Japanese readers/speakers, does the term Bishojo have a specific age range?

Tags: grammar, meaning, manga

I was wondering this about the term Bishojo. So about the 美少女? , I was curious on some points. I read Fairy Tail and there is one character(Lucy) whose 17 at the start and time passes and when it ends I believe their age is 20 or so.

So I've seen figures of them here released after the series ends and they use the word Bishojo:

https://hobby.dengeki.com/news/1009509/

and here about them:

https://animemiru.jp/articles/22620/

So I was wondering does it mean the character is not 20 and I was wrong about their age and all

Comment: Wikipedia says Lucy is 17 -> 18 years old. https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A6%96%E7%B2%BE%E3%81%AE%E5%B0%BB%E5%B0%BE#%E4%B8%BB%E8%A6%81%E4%BA%BA%E7%89%A9%EF%BC%88%E6%9C%80%E5%BC%B7%E3%83%81%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%EF%BC%89

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: @istrasci On its own this question seems fine. However this user has been spamming similar age-related questions on both this website and various subreddits for a couple of days now. (Not the downvoter, though)

Comment: @sundowner There is more on more timeskip at the end, so she should be 19-20 by then.  However does the term used mean she's not 20 or under 20?

Comment: Just like English *girl* has some vague range, you can't be 100% sure about her age just by 少女 being used for a woman. You may have better luck if you phrase the question into a question about timeline in Fairy Tail and ask it in Anime SE. Note that if the manga does not mention how much time elapsed during the time skips, it would be simply impossible to tell what age they have.

Comment: doesn't bishojo imply under 20 @sundowner? So for her does it mean she's not 20 for sure?

Comment: I'm saying it's not 100%. As answers to your 少年 question say, applying 少女/少年 to someone > 20 years old is not that odd. Also, the link you posted says 美少女っぷり and doesn't directly say Lucy is a 美少女. It just refers to the pretty girl aspect of Lucy. It's just impossible to infer the exact age from the word usage alone.

Comment: @sundowner What about the 2nd link blog?

Comment: It says 美少女ヒロイン, which is natural enough since she was 17? years old at the beginning (and probably for most of the story). It does not imply anything how old she was *in the end*. Again, if you are interested in her age in the final chapter of the manga, you are going the wrong way. It is purely about the story and not something deducible from what she's called.

Comment: @istrasci this is essentially the 5th (or more) question by the same user that boils down to "does the use of [some word] prove or disprove my vague time-related math for one particular manga."

Comment: @sundowner I mean the figure is her from the final season when she's 19. Does that make sense? Also well if she's currently 20 can she be called that? also does that mean she's meant to be a child or young adult?

Comment: @sundowner she's 18 for the most. Also could this 美少女っぷり  be applied to someone whose 20+

Answer (score 3):

When used in a serious novel or news article, the word 少女 **usually** refers to a girl roughly between 8 and 17.

However, the word **美**少女 (with 美) in the context of anime/manga/idol is a **genre** name that vaguely refers to attractive young women in general, and people do not think it strictly refers to girls under 17. Many 美少女ゲーム and 美少女アニメ feature cute women older than 20, 30 or more. For example, [Frieren](https://frieren.fandom.com/wiki/Frieren) is an anime heroine who is more than 1000 years old, but no one would say she is not categorized as a 美少女. No one will complain if her figure is sold in the 美少女フィギュア section of a hobby shop.

Comment: Does the same apply to ”美少年”?

Comment: @Zorf Yes, it's common to refer to a 25-yo male in the context of idols.

Comment: @naruto Hello so Lucy can be 20 years old and called a bishojo?